# Blue rectangle with arrow next to link

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, hyperlink, mozilla

in some pages I found some strange character next to hyperlinks. This is in IE and in Firefox also (see picture)

http://abload.de/image.php?img=arrow37kdx.png

Anyone know what this character is for, how it is named and how we can disable this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is to indicate that the link is to another site/domain.
It is used in wikipedia for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow. It is not on all sites (my links are not SO links, but there is no icon).

It seems that this is usually an image, added with CSS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:External_link_icons.
Unless you modify the css with greasemonkey for instance, you cannot remove them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i forgot to mention that the picture above is from one wikipedia page. What do you mean with "for instance"? What is the differenece between those links with and without this symbol? Can you disable this?